# recenter *xref* buffer on next-error

Tags: hooks, xref

I have a `next-error-hook` to recenter the `next-error-last-buffer`, so if the buffer is displayed, it will recenter to the line of the error I just jumped to:

```
(defun jpk/next-error-hook ()
  (let ((win (get-buffer-window next-error-last-buffer))
        (buf (buffer-name next-error-last-buffer))
        (recenter-redisplay nil))
    (when (and win (not (string= "*xref*" buf)))
      (with-selected-window win ;; this is what breaks xref
        (recenter)))))
(add-hook 'next-error-hook #'jpk/next-error-hook)
```

Lately I've been trying out xref, and it breaks on the `with-selected-window` (hence the hacky check for the buffer name); I can replace the `(recenter)` with `t` and it breaks in the same way.  It seems to only see two matches: the one last clicked on and the next; `previous-error` and `next-error` cycle between only these two.  All other modes that work with `next-error` (grep, compile, ggtags, rg, etc.) do not have this problem.  This also happens with multiple xref backends (elisp, gxref).

How can I write a `next-error-hook` to recenter the `*xref*` buffer?

Comment: Perhaps there is an Emacs bug here? Should `xref` be an exception in this way? If you think there might be a bug here, consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Are you looking for https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/32519 ?

Comment: @phils No, I'm aware of  `next-error-recenter` and have it set to `'(4)`.  That recenters in the linked-to buffer, I want to recenter in the link buffer (`next-error-last-buffer`).